# how to take a second order transfer function without any zeros and represent it using two first order transfer functions

Tags: transfer-function, control-systems

does anybody know how to take a second order transfer function with no zeros (no s terms in the numerator):

$$ g(s) = K\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2} $$

and represent it using two first order transfer functions.

the layout for my second order transfer function is

```
     (number)/((number)s^2 + (number)s + (number))
```

this second order transfer function was previously in the form

(number)/((number) s + (number))^2 before i expanded the brackets

Comment: Not clear, you want to represent G(s) by 2 1st-order transfer function having the same denominator ?

Comment: and generally, you simply need to factorize the polynomial. $$ \frac{-b± \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $|\zeta| \le 1$, let $\zeta= \cos\theta$, so $\theta=\mathrm{arccos}\,\zeta$

$$\begin{align*}g(s) &= K\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2}\\
\\
&= K\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\omega_n s \cos\theta+ \omega_n^2(\cos^2\theta +\sin^2\theta)}\\
\\
&= K\frac{\omega_n^2}{(s + \omega_n \cos\theta)^2+ \omega_n^2\sin^2\theta}\\
\\
&= \sqrt{K}\frac{\omega_n}{s + \omega_n \cos\theta + j\omega_n\sin\theta} \cdot \sqrt{K}\frac{\omega_n}{s + \omega_n \cos\theta  -j\omega_n\sin\theta} \\
\\
&= \sqrt{K}\frac{\omega_n}{s + \omega_n e^{j\theta}} \cdot \sqrt{K}\frac{\omega_n}{s + \omega_n e^{-j\theta}} \\
\\
\end{align*}$$

For $|\zeta| \ge 1$, since $\cosh\theta \ge 1$, let $\zeta= \pm\cosh\theta$, so $\theta=\mathrm{acosh}\,\left(\pm\zeta\right)$

$$\begin{align*}g(s) &= K\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2}\\
\\
&= K\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 \pm 2\omega_n s \cosh\theta+ \omega_n^2(\cosh^2\theta -\sinh^2\theta)}\\
\\
&= K\frac{\omega_n^2}{(s \pm \omega_n \cosh\theta)^2- \omega_n^2\sinh^2\theta}\\
\\
&= \sqrt{K}\frac{\omega_n}{s \pm \omega_n \cosh\theta + \omega_n\sinh\theta} \cdot \sqrt{K}\frac{\omega_n}{s \pm \omega_n \cosh\theta  -\omega_n\sinh\theta} \\
\\
&= \sqrt{K}\frac{\omega_n}{s \pm \omega_n e^{\theta}} \cdot \sqrt{K}\frac{\omega_n}{s \pm \omega_n e^{-\theta}} \\
\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You assume that the poles are complex. There's the second case there the poles are real.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, I made the assumption that $\xi \in [-1,1]$.  $\xi = \pm \cosh \theta$ could be used for $\xi$ not in that range.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of the quadratic equation $s^2 + 2\xi \omega_n + \omega_n^2=0$ are $s_{1,2} = -\xi w_n \pm \omega_n \sqrt{\xi^2 - 1} = -\xi w_n \pm i\omega_n \sqrt{1 - \xi^2}$ where we define the damping frequency $\omega_d = \omega_n \sqrt{1 - \xi^2}$ when $\xi < 1$. Therefore, the usual second order transfer function $\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\xi \omega_n + \omega_n^2=0} = \frac{\omega_n}{s-(-\xi w_n + i \omega_d)} \cdot \frac{\omega_n}{s-(-\xi w_n - i \omega_d)}$.